# C# binary serialization fail

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I used the following codes to serialize an object of a custom class (which also has some members that are also custom classes):

```
    MyType engine = new MyType(...);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(fs, engine);
}
```

After running the code, I am getting a file which doesnt seem to have the right contents to capture the object:

```
          :Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Also, when I deserialized the object, i am getting an error:

*End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.*

After I added to all related custom classes the attribute [Serializable]. The output file looks more like correct now in that it has detailed data of the object in the file.  But then I am getting another different error when I deserialized:

*Unable to find assembly 'Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.*

Any advice a appreciated.

Comment: Did you forget to Dispose the Stream? And: [BinaryFormatter is dangerous and obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)

Comment: Actually, I just rewrite the code above with a using block.  I got a non-zero size file, but the file doesnt seem to capture the object I want to serailize. This is the file content:                :Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Comment: Please use [edit] to add the changes to your question. It would be more readable than comments here.....

Comment: and when i tried derialize the file above, it fails... wonder if there is additional requirements on the class design except adding the attribute Serializable  to make this work

Comment: When it fails, please add the complete error description (or should we **_guess_** )?

Comment: Have you tried to add the Serializable Attribute to your type and all of its custom children?

Comment: I didnt know you need to add that attribute for the type of each member in the class.  I tried again by adding Serializable  attribute to all related custom classes...but still getting the same result...

Comment: *End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.* -- please [edit] your question to add a [mcve] showing serializable classes and code that reproduces the problem, as suggested by [ask].

Comment: Also, see [BinaryFormatter Obsoletion Strategy](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md) by MSFT which states that *In .NET 9.0, the entirety of the `BinaryFormatter` infrastructure will be removed from the product.*  So I don't recommend using `BinaryFormatter` for any new code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyType {
    public int a;
    public int b;
}
```

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyType engine = new MyType();
        engine.a = 2;
        engine.b = 4;
        File.Delete("d:\\temp\\test.bin");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("d:\\temp\\test.bin", FileMode.CreateNew);
        //Format the object as Binary
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        //It serialize the employee object
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0011
        formatter.Serialize(fs, engine);
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0011
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();

        fs = new FileStream("d:\\temp\\test.bin", FileMode.Open);

#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0011
        MyType engine2 = (MyType)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0011
        System.Console.WriteLine();
        System.Console.WriteLine($"engine2.a = {engine2.a}");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"engine2.b = {engine2.b}");
    }
}
```

output:

```
engine2.a = 2
engine2.b = 4
```